# How Inheritance can be implemented in c#?

Tags: c#

This may be a silly question but I want the exact idea about inheritance in c#.

Comment: You need to be much more specific.  Your question is so broad it could mean anything.

Comment: nah, Draco's answer does it for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inheritance in C# is the same as in any other language, only syntax is different

[Here a c# example](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson08.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The concept of inheritance is not unique for any type of language. However the difference lies in how inheritance works in c#. For instance you can inherit from only one base class but yet implement multiple interfaces. In order to override a method or property in a derived class you will have to declare the member as virtual in the base class. For more information you can delve into the documentation for c# inheritance [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx#)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpintro01.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For complete information on Inheritance visit the link below:

this is a book covering the basics of C#. you can go through it and use it to get the knowledge of other stuff also.

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=8R451rZJ5o0C&pg=PA506&lpg=PA506&dq=Inheritance+across+Packages+C%23&source=bl&ots=dO-5ccGNoS&sig=cMq-guLDXaL2n7Tbmgsd6f68YzA&hl=en&ei=2puvScv_Cc-_kAXW_Jm9BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=3&ct=result#PPA464,M1